# why Object.prototype.toString return [object Object]

Tags: javascript, oop

my code is shown below

```js
var obj = { name: 'John' }
var x = obj.toString();// produce "[object Object]"

alert(x)
```

i want to know why `Object.prototype.toString` is implemented to return `[object Object]` and why It's not implemented to return `"{name: 'John'}"` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See answers from @Leo and @Joel Gregory for an explanation from the spec. You can display an objects' contents using `JSON.stringify`, e.g.:

```js
const log = (...args) => document.querySelector("pre").textContent += `${args.join("\n")}\n`;
const obj = { name: 'John' }

log(obj.toString());
log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 8):

According to [**ECMAScript Language Specification**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.2):

> 15.2.4.2 Object.prototype.toString ( ) When the toString method is called, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. If the this value is undefined, return "[object Undefined]".
> 2. If the this value is null, return "[object Null]".
> 3. Let O be the result of calling ToObject passing the this value as the argument.
> 4. Let class be the value of the [[Class]] internal property of O.
> 5. Return the String value that is the result of concatenating the three Strings "[object ", class, and "]".

The language is designed like this. You'd have to ask Brendan Eich, or TC39, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

From Mozilla https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString:

*Every object has a toString() method that is automatically called when the object is to be represented as a text value or when an object is referred to in a manner in which a string is expected. By default, the toString() method is inherited by every object descended from Object. If this method is not overridden in a custom object, toString() returns "[object type]", where type is the object type.*