# two different outputs using the + vs , concatenating methods

Tags: javascript, concatenation

While working on this example at MDN site explaining the filter method:

```
var arr = [
  { id: 15 },
  { id: -1 },
  { id: 0 },
  { id: 3 },
  { id: 12.2 },
  { },
  { id: null },
  { id: NaN },
  { id: 'undefined' }
];

var invalidEntries = 0;

function isNumber(obj) {
  return obj!== undefined && typeof(obj) === 'number' && !isNaN(obj);
}

function filterByID(item) {
  if (isNumber(item.id)) {
    return true;
  } 
  invalidEntries++;
  return false; 
}

var arrByID = arr.filter(filterByID);

console.log('Filtered Array\n', arrByID); 
// Filtered Array
// [{ id: 15 }, { id: -1 }, { id: 0 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 12.2 }]

console.log('Number of Invalid Entries = ', invalidEntries); 
// Number of Invalid Entries = 4
```

This gets output in FireBug, as expected:

```
Filtered array

[Object { id=15}, Object { id=-1}, Object { id=0}, Object { id=3}, Object { id=12.2}]
Number of Invalid Entries: 4
```

But I initially, errantly but intentionally typed the first console.log(); statement as:

```
  console.log('Filtered array\n' + arrById);
```

and got this FireBug output:

```
Filtered array
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Number of Invalid Entries: 4
```

Why the different outputs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concatting with the `+` calls `toString` method on the obj and so returns the string 'object' instead of returning the obj property (name: value) as is returned using the `,` to concat by the console.log() output.

Answer (score 1):

Take this simple object:

```
var obj = {
  test: 5,
  another: 'hello'
}
```

If you do this `console.log(obj)`, what you are asking firebug to do is log your object. It knows how to deal with an object in a nice way, showing you all the properties and values.

However if you do this `console.log(obj.toString())`, you are asking javascript to convert your object to a string before asking firebug how to display it. Being a string, firebug will simply display it as is. So the real question is, *why does javascript convert an object to a string like `[object Object] ...`?*. You can see an explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27731321/277697)

In your question, by using the `+`, you are forcing the object to be converted to a string so that it can be concatenated with the `'Filtered array\n'` bit.

---

If you want to do what you have put in your question, but still have somewhat useful outputs, you can try `JSON.stringify()`. For example: `console.log('Filtered array\n' + JSON.stringify(arrById));`

Comment: +1 This is a more complete answer with a great link for a more detailed explanation calling toSting() on objs.