# aData is not fetching in fnRowCallback while using Datatables

Tags: ajax, datatable

Here is my code. I tried to alert the data in a particular row, but I keep getting undefined error.

I tried to print aData using **aData.toString()**, I'm getting [object] [object] as response. how do I debug the contents of **aData**?

**My Code:**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#datatable').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: false,
        order: [[1, 'asc']],
        "aoColumnDefs": [ { "sClass": "hide_me", "aTargets": [ 0 ], visible: false } ], // first column in visible columns array gets class "hide_me"
        ajax: {
            url: "/getData",
            dataSrc: "list"
        },
        columns: [
            { data : "_id"},
            { data : "user.name" },
            { data : "student.name" },
            { data : "class" },
            { data : "status" },
       ],
       "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
         alert(aData.[4]);
         if ( aData[4] == true )
         {
           $('td:eq(4)', nRow).html( '<b>On</b>' );
         }
         else {
           $('td:eq(4)', nRow).html( '<b>Off</b>' );
         }
       },
        responsive: true

     });

    });
```

Comment: `toString()` return `[object] [object]` because it is a....object literal! More precisely a JSON item.  You could use `console.log()` or `console dir()`. Also, your JSON item is not an array, so use `alert(aData.status)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why Object.prototype.toString return \[object Object\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27731303/why-object-prototype-tostring-return-object-object)

Comment: @davidkonrad Thanks,  aData.status worked.